# Using ScrollIntoView on DataGrid with Checkbox changes behavior

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I seem to have conflicting requirements. I have a DataGrid that has a checkbox as the first column. The users want the checkbox to be selectable with a single click, not a double click. I was able to make that happen by using a DataGridTemplateColumn and a checkbox like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The user also a control that allows them to specify a row (there can be hundreds of rows). If they specify a row that isn't in view I want it to scroll into view. I compromised and added an event handler in the code behind for the DataGrid_SelectionChanged event. Originally I was just using the ScrollIntoView command but offscreen rows would get highlighted but the grid did not scroll them into view. I was then able to add a Focus command and the row scrolled into view. So now the event handler looks like this:

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;
   if (dg.SelectedItem == null) return;
   dg.ScrollIntoView(dg.SelectedItem);
   dg.SelectedItem.Focus();
}
```

Now I'm back to the original problem, the row scrolls into view but to check the checkbox on any other row (that you don't move into via the jump to row control) you have to click twice. Anybody know what is causing the rows moved to manually to require double clicks?

Comment: I wasnt able to get the `dg.SelectedItem.Focus()` method.  Are you sure this is the code you have?  Regardless, without it I was able to get the dataGrid to scroll the selectedItem into view (I assume, in another control you set the selectedItem), and the single click checkbox dataTemplate worked like a charm on all the other rows as well... Is there something I'm missing from your code examples?

Comment: Your right, I thought I copied and pasted but I was trying so many things (and getting a bit frustrated) I can no longer be sure what caused the problem but I did find an answer.

Comment: Well at least it's working :P

Comment: Yeah but I'm not sure I'll be able to resist trying to resurrect the version I had that was setting focus and disabling the checkbox, I might be losing my mind. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it to work with the following code which was inspired by some tangentially related posts on getting the focus into cells. I have no clue as to why ScrollIntoView doesn't work, working or why performing the last three lines was the one way I could get the row to scroll into view without disabling the checkbox.

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;
    if (dg.SelectedItem == null) return;
    dg.ScrollIntoView(dg.SelectedItem);

    DataGridRow dg_row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dg.SelectedItem);
    if (dg_row == null) return;
    dg_row.Focus();
    }
```